# Action from dynamically created element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple code where there are input fields which a user can add and remove by using the + and - icons. But it's working only for the first time and the newly created icons are not working.

**[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L35uL01z/)**

```
$(".glyphicon-plus").on('click',function(){
  var Class = $(this).attr('class');
  var $parent = $(this).parent();

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "text";
  input.className = Class;

  var iconp = document.createElement('i');
  iconp.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus";
  //    iconp.className = "glyphicon-plus"

  var iconr = document.createElement('i');
  iconr.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus";
  //    iconr.className = "glyphicon-remove";

  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(iconp);
  div.appendChild(iconr);

  $(div).insertAfter($parent);
})
```

And what is the reason that the new inputs and the primitive input have different width and new + and - are closer now?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/L35uL01z/2/)**.

You've to use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to deal with new elements added to the DOM dynamically :

```
$("body").on('click',".glyphicon-plus",function(){
   //Your code here
});
```

**NOTE :** You should also remove the folowing line :

```
input.className = Class;
```

Since it give a `glyphicon-plus` class to the input field so it will be clickable too.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("body").on('click',".glyphicon-plus",function(){
  var Class = $(this).attr('class');
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  
  input.type = "text";

  var iconp = document.createElement('i');
  iconp.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus";
  // iconp.className = "glyphicon-plus"

  var iconr = document.createElement('i');
  iconr.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus";
  // iconr.className = "glyphicon-remove";

  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(iconp);
  div.appendChild(iconr);

  $(div).insertAfter($parent);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <input type = "text" class = "arrays" />
  <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
  <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: it is creating new input fieldse even i click on on the input field only, try to type something in them

Comment: Yes, that because of this line `input.className = Class;` that give the class `glyphicon-plus` to the input, just remove it it will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/L35uL01z/2/

Comment: i just got the error, i am by mistake puttin the Class variable to the input as well. Thanx